How to center text vertically in tabular cells using Beamer?
The text is bottom-aligned in tabular cells using the Beamer class.
I've tried solutions from answers to previous questions, but none works for me.
They include using multicolumn, multirow, parbox, minipage, a nested tabular environment, etc.
Here's a minimal working example:
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{diagbox}
\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}
   
  \begin{frame}
     \begin{center}
       \vspace{\baselineskip}
       \begin{table}
       \begin{tabular}{|m{3cm}|c|c|}
          \hline
          \diagbox[width=3cm]{Text}{Text} & Text & Text\\
          \hline
          Text & \includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image-a}  & \includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image-a} \\
          \hline
          Text & \includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image-a}  & \includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image-a} \\
          \hline
       \end{tabular}
       \end{table}
     \end{center}
  \end{frame}

\end{document}

Here's this code on Overleaf:
https://www.overleaf.com/read/xyhxppcggcxw#b44e1e
Here's a copy you can edit:
https://www.overleaf.com/2546442868dkwtxcdnvryn#708448

You could use the valign=... option from adjustbox to chang ethe vertical alignment of your images:
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{diagbox}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}

\begin{document}
   
  \begin{frame}
       \begin{table}
       \begin{tabular}{|m{3cm}|c|c|}
          \hline
          \diagbox[width=3cm]{Text}{Text} & Text & Text\\
          \hline
          Text & \includegraphics[width=3cm,valign=c]{example-image-a}  & \includegraphics[width=3cm,valign=c]{example-image-a} \\
          \hline
          Text & \includegraphics[width=3cm,valign=c]{example-image-a}  & \includegraphics[width=3cm,valign=c]{example-image-a} \\
          \hline
       \end{tabular}
       \end{table}
  \end{frame}

\end{document}



Thank you. My problem was with the alignment of the text. I don't understand why the figures' alignment affects the text's alignment, but it works.

@LeonardoCastro By default a figure is treated like any other letter and placed on the same baseline.
